# Invalid column index for JDBC insert with sequence number

Tags: java, jdbc

Below is my code:
I'm passing three parameters to method insertRecordIntoTable which will execute JDBC insert query but I'm receiving Invalid column index.

Below are log statements which got printed:

Inside insertRecordIntoTable

ID from sequence 14

Invalid column index

```
private static void insertRecordIntoTable(String userName, String targetEmail, String siteName) throws SQLException {

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        System.out.println("Inside insertRecordIntoTable ");
        String insertTableSQL = "insert into TableName values(?,?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

                        ResultSet srs = preparedStatement.executeQuery("SELECT id_seq.NEXTVAL FROM dual");
                if ( srs!=null && srs.next() ) {
                    int myId = srs.getInt(1);
                    System.out.println("ID from sequence "+myId);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(1, myId);
                    System.out.println("Inserted ID value "+myId);
                    srs.close();
                }

                preparedStatement.setString(2, userName);
                System.out.println("Inserted username value "+userName);

                preparedStatement.setString(3, targetEmail);
                System.out.println("Inserted targetEmail value "+targetEmail);

                preparedStatement.setString(4, siteName);
                System.out.println("Inserted sitecode value "+siteName);

                preparedStatement.setTimestamp(5, getCurrentTimeStamp());
                System.out.println("Inserted date value "+getCurrentTimeStamp());

                preparedStatement .executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("Inserted values ");
                System.out.println("Inserted name & email into the table..."); 

            // execute insert SQL stetement
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same PreparedStatement variable twice

```
preparedStatement.executeQuery("SELECT id_....);
```

Create and use another variable for this Query else the original Query will be overwritten.

Also consider what is going to happen if

```
if ( srs!=null && srs.next() ) {
```

returns false

Comment: Thank you. I have created a new preparedStatement variable and it worked!